# Set operations between sets with predicates.

Tags: set-theory

$\newcommand{\Set}[2]{%
  \{\, #1 \mid #2 \, \}%
}$

I'm working with a language called [tuple relational calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_relational_calculus) which uses sets in a form $$S = \Set{t}{P(t)},$$
where $t$ is a named set of tuples from a database table (rows) and $P(t)$ is a first-order logic predicate working with $t$ giving either $true$ or $false$.

An example of such a set could be

$$ 
S = \Set{\mathrm{Employee}}{\mathrm{Employee.name} \neq \mathrm{John} \land \mathrm{Employee.age} \leq 42}.
$$

Given the above, how would one go about joining the sets
$$ 
\begin{align}
E_{1} &= \Set{t}{P(t)}, \\
E_{2} &= \Set{t}{Q(t)}
\end{align}
$$
with formal set operators $\cup, \cap, \setminus$?

I propose that

$$
\begin{align}
E_{1} \cup E_{2} &= \Set{t}{P(t)} \cup \Set{t}{Q(t)} = \Set{t}{P(t) \lor Q(t)}, \\
E_{1} \cap E_{2} &= \Set{t}{P(t)} \cap \Set{t}{Q(t)} = \Set{t}{P(t) \land Q(t)}, \\
E_{1} \setminus E_{2} &= \Set{t}{P(t)} \setminus \Set{t}{Q(t)} = \Set{t}{P(t) \land (\lnot Q(t))}.
\end{align}
$$

Are these types of sets defined anywhere else? I've seen them being used in a lot of unrelated situations in mathematics but I seem to be unable to find any data on how to work with them.

Comment: These are basic Boolean set operations — *and*, *or*, *but not* — so "data on how to work with them" abounds. But it seems like you're interested in the correspondence between  operations on the set comprehensions and predicates. Your equalities are all correct: union of the set comprehensions equals a comprehension with disjunction of the predicates, and analogously for the other operations. Similarly, projection of one of your comprehensions (dropping some columns) corresponds to existential quantification of the predicate over the variables corresponding to the dropped columns.

Comment: Thank your for your comment. I'm interested in what you wrote in the last sentence. It seems right from the excercises I made. Have you got a source for such conversion or is it just a well known fact? I would also be interested in a conversion of selection (and possibly renaming but that does not exist in relational calculi) so it would come in handy.

Comment: No source for that, it’s just… true :) No doubt it’s written out somewhere, but you should try your hand at it. It’s just a matter of expanding two definitions of sets and seeing they’re the same set. // As for renaming, no, the theory of relationa is separate: math vwriables aren’t *names* that can be bound and re-bound. Think of column names as given by a separately – say. by a function from columns to strings.

Comment: $\newcommand{\Set}[2]{%
  \{\, #1 \mid #2 \, \}%
}$
Yes, I can claim many things but I need to know if it's right. In the meantime I think I figured out selection:
$ \sigma_{P(x)}(E) \iff \sigma_{P(x)}(\{ t \mid Q(x) \}) \iff \{ t \mid P(x) \land Q(x)\}.$
and the only thing remaining is cross product which will take me a while.

Answer (score 1):

The situation that you are describing - using conjunctions, disjunctions and negations to represent, respectively, intersections, unions and complements, is pretty common in maths indeed, and in most cases if not all, it will be what is taken as the definition of the set theoretic operations. That is intuitive when we think about sets, since something is in the union either if it is in the first set, or if it is in the second; and in the intersection ifit is in both, and so on.

You can find a description of this in any book that touches on naive set theory, or has some elementary set theory introduction.